# Creating object for APIClient() causing wiping out all the data in database

Tags: django, rest, django-rest-framework

I am writing unit tests functions for django rest-api views,the moment I create client object..data in my database tables getting truncated... can come body help me why this is happening???

```
from rest_framework.test import APIClient, APIRequestFactory
class TestMapApi(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
```

I am using viewsets and routers of django rest-api

Answer (score 1):

Doesn't the `APITestCase` already setup a `client`? 
http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/testing#test-cases

Also, if you mean existing data from your database isn't accessible, usually a test case sets up it's own data. Ideally, one test case should not leave data behind so they usually create a temporary db and truncate that at the end of the test. So in that `setUp` you should set up any data needed in the test case.